# How to use "or" in freemarker templates

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to change the layout of a data table based on the presence or lack of data. What I would LIKE to write but does not function is:

```
<#if record.enduseraccount?has_content OR record.installedataccount?has_content>
  Table 1
<#else>
  table 2
</#if>
```

I don't need both statements to be true, just one or the other. I really don't want to have to add massive length to my template by adding a new table for each variable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `||`

Please see the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_logicalop)

Also you can use [double question mark](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test) `??` to check if the value is missing or not

```
<#if record.enduseraccount?? || record.installedataccount??> ....
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you believe I have searched for the answer to my question at least twice a week for the last month...